# Updating records from selected row in a list using mvc, php, pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

Hi Guys please assist with the below code,
I want to update a selected record using MVC, MVC that does not include view object declaration in the model.

-my code list members.
-allow for clicking edit selcted record.
-validates user against fields...
else I call method for updating.

after clicking update I get no updates. please assist I have got a jobbut I cant update, and I might get fired. please.

Controller - Index.php

```
<?php 
require('db/ABSA/conn.php'); 
require('model.php'); 

$conn = new Connect_to_db();
$conn->Connect_db();

$m = new model();

if (isset($_POST['action'])) { 
$action = $_POST['action']; 
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action']; } else {
$action = 'view_members'; 
 $members = $m->getDetails(); 
 include('view_members.php');
}
if ($action == 'update_members') { 

global $member_id;
$member_id= $_GET['member_id'];// Get the current  ID 
$members = $m->getDetails_member($member_id);
//var_dump($members);
//var_dump($member_id);

$fname = $_POST['First_Name'];
$id_num = $_POST['ID_Number'];
$checkdate = $_POST['Checked_Date'];
$checked_by = $_POST['Checked_by'];

if(empty($fname)){
echo "Please enter fname!";include('update_members.php');exit;
header('Refresh: 3; url=index.php');

}else
if(empty($id_num)){
echo "Please enter id_num";include('update_members.php');exit;
header('Refresh: 3; url=index.php');

}
if(empty($checkdate)){
echo "Please enter checkdate!";include('update_members.php');exit;
header('Refresh: 3; url=index.php');

}else
if(empty($checked_by)){
echo "Please enter checked_by";include('update_members.php');exit;


}
else{

$member_i= $_GET['member_id'];

$m->update_members($member_i,$fname,$id_num,$checkdate,$checked_by);
header('Refresh: 4; url=index.php');
}   
}

 ?>
```

Here is my view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<title>Update and view </title><link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u' crossorigin='anonymous'>
</head>
</head>
     <div class="container">
      </br>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                <th>Member ID   </th>
                <th>First Name </th>
                <th> ID Number </th>
                <th>Checked Date </th>
                <th>Checked by</th>         
                    </tr>         
                   <?php    foreach($members as $row):                      
                            echo "
                                 <td>$row[m_id]</td>
                                 <td>$row[First_Name]</td>
                                 <td>$row[ID_Number]</td>
                                 <td>$row[Checked_Date]</td>
                                 <td>$row[Checked_by]</td>                           
                                 ";                         
                            ?>      
                        <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <form method='GET' action='index.php' >                                                       
                            <input type ="hidden" name="action" value="update_members" /> 
                            <input type ="hidden" name="member_id" value="<?php echo $row['m_id']; ?>" />
                            <input type = "submit" value="Edit">

                            </form>
                                </td>

                           </tr>
                           <?php endforeach;?>


            </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my model :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    /*
Author name         : Neo Lloyd Sono
Occupation          : Junior web developer@PLP Group 
Programme name      : Update and view leads members 
date                : 2016-09-09
place               : PLP Group, 10 hunter ...

*/
        //query, prepare, execute, and fetch,       


class model{

        function getDetails(){

            global $pdo;//globalize connection      
            $tbl_name = "leads";//use var for table
            $stm  =  $pdo->prepare("select * from $tbl_name");
            $stm->execute();

            while($row[] = $stm->fetch()){
            $i++;                       
            $row[$i] = $stm->fetch();
            }
            return $row;
        }
        public static function getDetails_member($id){

            global $pdo;//globalize connection      
            $tbl_name = "leads";//use var for table

            $stm  =  $pdo->prepare("select * from $tbl_name where m_id= :m_id limit 10 ");
            $stm->bindParam(':m_id',$id);
            $stm->execute();
            $row = $stm->fetch();
            return $row;
        }
         function update_members($id,$fname,$id_num,$checkdate,$checked_by){


            global $pdo;//globalize connection
            $tbl_name = "leads";//use var for table

            //$arr = array(":First_Name"=>$fname,":ID_"=>$id_num,":Checked_D"=>$checkdate,":checked_b"=>$checked_by,":id"=>$id);

            $stm  =  $pdo->prepare("update `leads` set `First_Name`     ='$fname',
                                                     `ID_Number`        ='$id_num',
                                                     `Checked_Date`     ='$checkdate',
                                                     `Checked_by`       ='$checked_by'
                                                     where `m_id`   ='$id'");

            $stm->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);                                       
            $stm->bindParam(':First',$fname,PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
            $stm->bindParam(':ID_',$id_num,PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
            $stm->bindParam(':Checked_D',$checkdate);
            $stm->bindParam(':Checked_b',$checked_by,PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);

            $stm->execute();

            if($stm){
                echo "Updated ";
            }else{
            echo "Not Updated ";

            }
            var_dump($member_id);
            var_dump($stm);
            return $stm;
        }
}
    ?>
```

here is my update records view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<title>Update and view </title>
     <div class="container">
      </br>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <tr>
                <th>Member ID   </th>
                <th>First Name </th>
                <th> ID Number </th>
                <th>Checked Date </th>
                <th>Checked by</th>         
                    </tr>       
                   <?php    

                   //var_dump($members);

                            ?>  <form method='post' action='.' ><td style = "color:white">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>                      
                                 <td><input type = 'text' value="<?php  echo $members['First_Name']; ?>"        name='First_Name'/></td>
                                 <td><input type = 'text' value="<?php echo $members['ID_Number'];  ?>"     name='ID_Number'/></td>
                                 <td><input type = 'text' value="<?php echo $members['Checked_Date']; ?>"   name='Checked_Date'/></td>
                                 <td><input type = 'text' value="<?php echo $members['Checked_by']; ?>"     name='Checked_by'/></td>                                

                            <tr><td>                


                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_members" /> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="<?php echo $members['m_id']; ?>" />
                            <input type = 'submit' name="u" value='Update' />
                            </td>
                            </form>
                           </tr>


            </table>
     </form>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i dump my update stament :  i get              : ct(PDOStatement)[4]
  public 'queryString' => string 'update `leads` set `First_Name`  ='Neo',

              `ID_Number`  ='12346',

              `Checked_Date`  ='2016-09-09',

              `Checked_by`  ='Checked_by'

              where `m_id`  =''' (length=200)

Comment: Note that ID id is empty when I call the method, however it is not empty in the index page when I dump $member_id, that equals $_GET['member_id'] from hidden field in my view or list... and the : $val = getDetails_member($id); equals an existing row from db... and I do not know where I am losing logic, by the way am new to PHP MVC OOP. thanks for lending me your time.

Comment: Sorry, but questions seeking debugging help are off topic here.

Comment: You have to understand that this immediate help won't make you a programmer this very instant. And you will be fired on the next occasion. Don't you think of coming here every day asking other people to do your job for you, do you?

Comment: No problem :( however, everybody needs help at some point...